# Media Query breakpoint 1218px

Tags: css, media-queries, squarespace

I'm working on this site (https://stagetoday.squarespace.com/) but I need to write a media query in css for the breakpoint 1218px.

When I pass that width my site subtitle jumps under my menu item about, but it has to stay above it off course.

I already have a media query for 640px breakpoint, there everything aligns in the center and that is okay, but between 640px and 1218px the menu on the right isn't how I want it.

Can anyone help me with this media query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `width:80% !important` for `#navigator .logo-subtitle` to `width:auto !important`.

```
#navigator .logo-subtitle{
    width:80% !important; // remove this and add the below style
    width:auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove width property from `#navigator .logo-subtitle`.